Finding Octahedral and Tetrahedral sites
I am very new to material research. I am trying to find the xyz coordinates of all tetrahedral and octahedral sites of  Pd (110) plane. I will be grateful if you could  point out the xyz coordinates or make a code to find these sites. The xyz coordinates of Pd is mentioned below. Thanks for your help.
35

- Pd    1.384975    1.958651    4.154926
- Pd    4.154926    1.958651    4.154926
- Pd    4.154926    1.958651    6.924876
- Pd    1.384975    1.958651    6.924876
- Pd    1.384975    1.958651    9.694827
- Pd    4.154926    1.958651    9.694827
- Pd    1.384975    5.875952    4.154926
- Pd    4.154926    5.875952    4.154926
- Pd    4.154926    5.875952    6.924876
- Pd    1.384975    5.875952    6.924876
- Pd    2.769950    3.917302    5.539901
- Pd    2.769950    3.917302    8.309852
- Pd    1.384975    5.875952    9.694827
- Pd    4.154926    5.875952    9.694827
- Pd    1.384975    9.793254    4.154926
- Pd    4.154926    9.793254    4.154926
- Pd    4.154926    9.793254    6.924876
- Pd    1.384975    9.793254    6.924876
- Pd    2.769950    7.834603    5.539901
- Pd    2.769950    7.834603    8.309852
- Pd    1.384975    9.793254    9.694827
- Pd    4.154926    9.793254    9.694827
- Pd    6.924876    1.958651    4.154926
- Pd    6.924876    1.958651    6.924876
- Pd    6.924876    1.958651    9.694827
- Pd    6.924876    5.875952    4.154926
- Pd    5.539901    3.917302    5.539901
- Pd    6.924876    5.875952    6.924876
- Pd    6.924876    5.875952    9.694827
- Pd    5.539901    3.917302    8.309852
- Pd    6.924876    9.793254    4.154926
- Pd    5.539901    7.834603    5.539901
- Pd    6.924876    9.793254    6.924876
- Pd    6.924876    9.793254    9.694827
- Pd    5.539901    7.834603    8.309852


+1. Welcome to our community.

In order to obtain the atoms' coordinates from Pd (110) plane, you need to start with an initial crystal structure. XYZ files doesn't have the information for periodicity of the system.
If you take a look at the Material Projects site, and search for Pb, you will find that there are four different Bravais lattices for Pb: cubic, hexagonal, trigonal and tetragonal.
You need to select the correct lattice for your system. After that, you will need a software, like VESTA, ASE or Cif2Cell, among others, load the download file and create the surface at the direction/plane you need.
